# SQL Insert based on role

Tags: sql, security, insert, key, default

I have a database with 3 tables:

Table 1 (Department) - This is a table with columns for departments and departmentID's

Table 2 (SecurityMap) - This is a table that maps rolenames to department ID's

Table 3 (customer info) - this is the info that is displayed to users based on their role memberships

I have all of the SELECT based on role functions working.

What I need is to figure out how to insert a specific value into the DepartmentID column within Table 3 by default, based on the users role membership.  For instance, when someone is adding a new row to the database - in addition to the data they are supplying within the "add" form, I need a default value inserted into this column.  If they are a member of the Marketing role, it should be a 1, if they are a member of the IT role, it should be a 2, etc...

Ideally, this would be done without any knowledge to the user that it is even happening.  I would assume that I need to use an "Instead Of" trigger, but I have no idea how to proceed....

Comment: Do you have a table that, for example, maps Marketing to Id 1, IT to Id 2?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too difficult:

1. In your app, keep track of the logged-in user and their role.
2. When your app saves the customer data, make sure it passes the database the role ID as well as the user-entered data (a stored procedure would be ideal here)
3. When the database processes the supplied data, it saves the role ID into the appropriate column.

Answer (score 0):

this should work provided the rolename-column (or id) is unique in the securityMap-table otherwise the select could return more than one value, maybe you need to select the departmentId differently then.

```
insert into customer_info(otherdata, departmentId) values('data', (select departmentId from securityMap where rolename = 'userrole'))
```

Edit:

since you mentioned db_owner maybe this can help you (from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic411310-338-1.aspx)

```
WITH CTE_Roles (role_principal_id)
AS
(
SELECT role_principal_id 
FROM sys.database_role_members
WHERE member_principal_id = USER_ID()
UNION ALL
SELECT drm.role_principal_id
FROM sys.database_role_members drm
  INNER JOIN CTE_Roles CR
    ON drm.member_principal_id = CR.role_principal_id
)
SELECT USER_NAME(role_principal_id) RoleName
FROM CTE_Roles
ORDER BY RoleName;
```

you could join that with the SecurityMap-table to filter out roles like db_owner

Comment: While this will get the correct ID for a specific role, the problem isn't solved.  The role will be dynamic, based on who is logged in.  In addition to that, although the users will be part of only one of the specific roles, they may also be part of the db_owner role.  I do feel closer to an answer though, thanks!

Comment: ok well i did not see how users are linked to their roles, ... db_owner ... ah do you mean database-roles, i was thinking about application roles, hm i will take a look into that